# Discord.py "The command is already an existing command or alias"

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()
client = discord.Client()

@bot.command()
async def commands():
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Commands")
    embed.add_field(name="$info", value="Shows info about the bot", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="$users", value="Shows how many members the server has", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def info():
    await message.channel.send("Bot feito por Ra'Ed#2931")

@bot.command()
async def users():
    await message.channel.send(f"""Esse server tem {id.member_count} membros""")

bot.add_command(commands)
bot.add_command(info)
bot.add_command(users)

client.run(token)
```

When i run this code i recive the following output:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command commands is already an existing command or alias.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()

@client.command()
async def comandos(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Commands")
    embed.add_field(name="$info", value="Shows info about the bot", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="$users", value="Shows how many members the server has", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Made by Ra'Ed#2931")

@client.command()
async def users(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"""This server has {id.member_count} members""")

client.run(token)
```

Changed code to this, added the paramater ctx to the functions, changed from bot to client, removed the bot.add_command() and now it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Hi the error telling you that "commands" command is already there so try to change it from commands to help.

i know you didn't add it but you are using it For Example: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')`

that code will work :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
bot.remove_command('help')

def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()
client = discord.Client()

@bot.command()
async def help():
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Commands")
    embed.add_field(name="$info", value="Shows info about the bot", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="$users", value="Shows how many members the server has", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def info():
    await message.channel.send("Bot feito por Ra'Ed#2931")

@bot.command()
async def users():
    await message.channel.send(f"""Esse server tem {id.member_count} membros""")

bot.add_command(commands)
bot.add_command(info)
bot.add_command(users)

client.run(token)
```

I changed it from "commands" to "help"

Comment: Din't work out, this time the problem was the same, but with the command help "The command help is already an existing command or alias." Even if i change it's name to something random.

Answer (score 0):

All the error means is that there is a command with the same name or with the name in its aliases that already exists. You will either have to find and change the command name, or change the current command name. You can't have 2 commands with the same name. I don't know what your other command is so I can't really tell you much either then this. Also, there is no reason to add the `bot.add_command("command_name")`.. it will automatically be understood.